# Preload background images with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div thats currently set to display none, The Div has a background image that is approx 5000px wide, 2000px high.

I toggle the div display attirbute with jquery on a button click only with the image being so big the div loads and the image loads 1/2 seconds afterwards; is there a function where I can show a preloader until the image is ready and then display it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use native javascript's `Image` object to preload the image.

Also consider about to avoid using such huge images on the web by making tiles for example.

Answer (score 5):

This question was posted up a while back and answered just using vanilla javascript, but can be adapted to your scenario pretty easily.

[Preloading CSS Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-background-images)

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var c = new Image();

    c.onload = function(){
        $("#Your Div ID").css("background-image", "url(Path to Background Image)");  
    }

    c.src = "Path to Background Image";

});
```

Comment: Just creating an event handler for when the image is loaded, which will apply the image to your div as a background. In your case, you'd want to make it into a function where you'd show your preloader first, then execute the code above to show the image when it's available (and hide your preloader). For more details on the image object:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://ditio.net/2010/02/14/jquery-preload-images-tutorial-and-example/