# Preload background-image using angularjs promises

Tags: css, angularjs, preload

How can I preload css background-image's using angularjs promises
What I want to do is something that I can use in this way:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    element.hide();
    url = attrs.url;
    preload(url).then(function(loadedImageURL){
        element.css({
            background-image: "url('" + loadedImageURL + "')"
        });
    });
    element.fadeIn();
}
```

Please note that this is not a duplicate question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-background-images).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
function preload(url) {
  var deffered = $q.defer(),
      image = new Image();

  image.src = url;

  if (image.complete) {

    deffered.resolve();

  } else {

    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
      deffered.resolve();
    });

    image.addEventListener('error', function() {
      deffered.reject();
    });
  }

  return deffered.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect. here's a demo plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xRvFiQ4m8l2XrMTBzBUp?p=preview

Comment: I would break it into a service, check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/mCsdts1AojaOpSbHFttW?p=preview