# Preload Images then use it as a Background in a div

Tags: javascript, css

i am trying to make a slider here in `javascript` and what am i trying to do is i am trying to have a single div and use the background image as the image placeholder which has the background size and cover property.
And i am trying to use navigation keys for loading previous and next images.
Now the problem is that how can i `preload` some images and use then as in `Bg` property so that when i click the next arrow, the **images do not have to wait for the next image as background for the div to load**.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar problem in this link:

[Preloading CSS Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images)

Comment: Yeah Biut when i click next button won't it take time to load the next image as background as opposed to the images in html which are already loaded. thanks.

Comment: I found something similar to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images