# How to use a mixin to create a string from an undefined length array in scss?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

The answer from here works for me for preloading images:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390213/533426

```
body::after{
    position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
    content:url(img01.png) url(img02.png) url(img03.png) url(img04.png);
}
```

I think instead of this `position, width` etc you can use `display: none` as well.

how can I create a mixin that takes an array of img urls and produces something like this:

`content:url(img01.png) url(img02.png) url(img03.png) url(img04.png);`

I was thinking of something like

```
@mixin preloadImgs($imgUrls){
  &:after{
    content: @each $imgUrl in imgUrls url('#{$imgUrl}');
    display: none;
  }
}
```

.

```
.test{
  @include preloadImgs(['img01.png', 'img02.png', 'img03png']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is **@function** and not **@mixin**. Mixins give one or more property-value style rules where as Functions in sass give just the value of a property.

```
@function getUrls($urls) {
  $allUrls: '';
  @each $url in $urls {
    $allUrls: #{$allUrls url($url)};
  }
  @return $allUrls
}

.class {
  color: getUrls('one' 'two');
}
```