# How to preload images only once

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, preload, image-preloader

I'm trying to preload images in my Vue.js project but looks like images loaded twice on hover.
My images preload code:

```js
    // Pre-load images
    [
      "/images/settings-click.png",
      "/images/poems-click.png",
    ].map((src) => {
      (new Image()).src = src;
    });
```

Both images loaded properly on the page load (1) but reloaded again after elements hover (2) with side effects.

[image]

The hover logic is in CSS:

```css
.settings:hover,
.settings:active,
.settings:focus {
  background: url("../images/settings-click.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.poems:hover,
.poems:active,
.poems:focus {
  background: url("../images/poems-click.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: What does the hover code look like?

Comment: You also have `Disable cache` enabled, so it isn't going to load the cached version.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I have enabled cache but situation is the same. How can I be sure that images will be loaded in any browser without side effects on hover?

Comment: There are some CSS only solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images