# Preloader background-images from CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

basically I have a variable that `main` that changes it's background image based on some triggers.
The way it's changes the background image is by adding another class for example `.main .bck-1` `.main .bck-2` and so on.

My question is how can I preload the background images of bck-1 bck-2 before changing it because my images it glitches on changing because the browser has to download the `background-images`

Comment: Please provide some code examples or jsfiddle

Comment: You can find a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images