# Preloading Background images seems to fail in NextJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to load all the images before removing the LOADING SCREEN using this code.
The loading works and it goes away when all the images are loaded, But When I try to use the images as background for a div, it takes time to load it again. I'll appreciate your advice

pages/index.tsx:

```js
export default function Home() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const images = [
      "/images/homePage/main-illustration.webp",
      "/images/homePage/title-logo-text.webp",
      "/images/homePage/title-logo-gear.webp"
    ];
    let loadedCount = 0;

    const checkIfAllLoaded = () => {
      loadedCount++;
      if (loadedCount === images.length) {
        setIsLoaded(true);
      }
    };

    images.forEach((src) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = checkIfAllLoaded;
      img.src = src;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        {!isLoaded && (
          <div>
            Loading...
          </div>
        )}
      {isLoaded && (
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <HomePage />
          <Footer />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

components/Hero.tsx

```js
const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-[url(/images/homePage/main-illustration.webp)] bg-cover">    
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Do any of the tecniques suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images help?

Comment: @AHaworth The mentioned solutions didn't work. I checked the network tab and the images are getting loaded twice. So the preloading seems to have no effect when I actually use the images later as background for div

Comment: So even the suggestion that you load them off-screen as backgrounds didn't work? (I can see why loading them as img elements might not work).

Comment: @AHaworth I checked all the methods and only the first one "Preloading images using CSS only" seems to work. So I create a div for every value inside my array and set the mentioned style to it, and then I append the div to the body. Thanks again for the help