How do I avoid flickering in slide show made with CSS animations?
I've made a simple slide show with CSS animations in Angular. It works well, but I encounter white flickering between images, which depends on image loading, I suppose.
Is there a way to avoid this flickering and make it seamless?
CSS file
.bg{
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    height: 100vh;

    animation: BgAnimation forwards;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes BgAnimation {
    0%   { background-image: url(../../assets/outro/1.jpg); }
    33%  { background-image: url(../../assets/outro/2.png); }
    66%  { background-image: url(../../assets/outro/3.jpg); }
    100%  { background-image: url(../../assets/outro/4.png); }
}

HTML file
<div class="bg"></div>


This solution also helped me a lot.

The angular way is to use ngOptimizedImage directive in your code then convert the code to work with image tags, instead of background image!
ngOptimizedImage getting started
ngOptimizedImage docs
We can use the pirority attribute to increase priority of the resource loading!
<img ngSrc="cat.jpg" width="400" height="200" priority>


You can use the below CSS, to preload the images (Since body tag is displayed on first load, which will immediately load the images mentioned in content), before the animation starts
body {
    position: relative;
}

body:after {
    content: url(https://placehold.co/600x400/000000/FFFFFF/png) url(https://placehold.co/600x400/FFFFFF/000000/png) url(https://placehold.co/600x400/000000/FFFFFF/png) url(https://placehold.co/600x400/FFFFFF/000000/png);
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
}

You can encode the images to base64 so that they are always present in the HTML, but note this  increases the size of your HTML page (waste of size), but this means, the image is immediately available!
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...");

base64 image encoder

This approach of hiding body:after works better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images
Yours works, but leaves empty spaces.

@Tuffling_Tony Could you try setting display: none might work!

Preloading the image can do the job that will help you reduce or completely remove the flickering.
<!-- Preloading images in the DOM -->
<img src="../../assets/outro/1.jpg" style="display:none;" alt="" />
<img src="../../assets/outro/2.png" style="display:none;" alt="" />
<img src="../../assets/outro/3.jpg" style="display:none;" alt="" />
<img src="../../assets/outro/4.png" style="display:none;" alt="" />

<!-- Or using the preload link tag -->
<link rel="preload" href="../../assets/outro/1.jpg" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="../../assets/outro/2.png" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="../../assets/outro/3.jpg" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="../../assets/outro/4.png" as="image">

There are better solutions but I found this one really easy to use especially for small applications.
